# Preventing the browser to unload after clicking the close button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, dom-events

Preventing the browser to unload after clicking the close button. At the same time I want to display the popup window having "save" and "anotherFunction" buttons. Now, the popup window is displaying, but parent window is closed after clicking the "close" button in the browser. How to prevent the unloading?.

My Code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    openwindow(200, 100, 'Close.aspx');
};
```

Comment: You cannot prevent the unloading only with Javascript. You could `return false` from the onbeforeload event handler which would open a dialogue to the user in which he/she can decided to stay on the page or to leave the page

Comment: Instead of `stay on the page or to leave the page`, I am having the window here.

Comment: No matter, window or page or dialog, the result of `onbeforeunload` varies in different browsers. Only common thing is, that it can't be cancelled...

Comment: **You cannot prevent the window from closing** - At best, you can ask for user confirmation (that too using a browser standard dialog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onbeforeunload` is a very strict event in which you cannot stop it from executing by no means. This is useful because if the developer of the site wanted to lock you in, what could you do?

If the assigned function to this event returns a non-void value, the user is shown a dialog box with the content (usually a string). If it returns a falsy value, no intervention happens.

**Read your documentations, people.**

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

For your case, you are showing a html dialog box but since it cannot stop the page being closed it is rendering itself invalid.

Comment: I guess somebody is angry and rage-downvoting me. Have fun in life bro

Comment: I'm not raging, you are simply wrong. "Bro"